# How to define a textfield from few ones and put the data from a custom numberpad (flutter)(SOLVED)

Tags: flutter, textfield

I have few textfields and a **custom numberpad**. And I want to add a number from my custom button in to a textfield that now **in a focus**. How can I define which textfield in a focus right now and how can i get acces to this *focused* controller to put a text inside? Thank you for someone who can help me...[image: appImage]

(**Updated. SOLVED. Solution below.**)

Here is my texfield widget:

```
class InputValue extends StatelessWidget {
  final String name;
  final String units;
  final double width;
  TextEditingController textFieldController = TextEditingController();

  InputValue(
      {required this.name,
      required this.units,
      this.width = 70,
      required this.textFieldController});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String labelText = name + units;

    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
            height: 30,
            width: width,
            child: TextField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.none,
              controller: textFieldController,
              maxLines: 1,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 1, 5, 1.0),
                  labelText: labelText,
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: const BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.blue),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                  ),
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: const BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.green),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                  )),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here is my numberPadButton:

```
class NumberPadButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String symbol;
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final Function onChange;
  final Function? onSubmit;
  NumberPadButton(
      {required this.symbol,
      required this.controller,
      required this.onChange,
      this.onSubmit});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          controller.text = symbol!;
          onChange();
        },
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(1),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: buttonBackgroundColor,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(1)),
          child: Center(
              child: Text(
            symbol!,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
          )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here is my State class:

```
class _MainViewState extends State<MainView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextEditingController sideAController = TextEditingController();
    TextEditingController sideBController = TextEditingController();
    TextEditingController sideCController = TextEditingController();
    TextEditingController alphaController = TextEditingController();
    TextEditingController bettaController = TextEditingController();
    TextEditingController gammaController = TextEditingController();
    TextEditingController numberPadController = TextEditingController();

    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          child: TriangleDrawing(
            triangle: widget.triangle,
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  InputValue(
                    name: 'side c',
                    units: '',
                    textFieldController: sideCController,
                  ),
                  InputValue(
                    name: 'side b',
                    units: '',
                    textFieldController: sideBController,
                  ),
                  InputValue(
                    name: 'side a',
                    units: '',
                    textFieldController: sideAController,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              // SizedBox(
              //   height: 15,
              // ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  InputValue(
                    name: alphaSymbol,
                    units: degreeSymbol,
                    textFieldController: alphaController,
                  ),
                  InputValue(
                    name: bettaSymbol,
                    units: degreeSymbol,
                    textFieldController: bettaController,
                  ),
                  InputValue(
                    name: gammaSymbol,
                    units: degreeSymbol,
                    textFieldController: gammaController,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        // TriangelPictureW(),
        SizedBox(
          height: 5,
        ),
        
        SizedBox(
          height: 5,
        ),
        Center(child: Text(widget.triangle.message)),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      NumberPadButton(
                        symbol: '1',
                        controller: numberPadController,
                        onChange: () {
                          if (FocusScope.of(context).hasFocus) {
//HERE SHOULD I DEFINE A TEXTFIELD?
//TEXTFIELD_IN_FOCUS.text += numberPadController.text;
                          } 
                          
                        },
                      ),
                      NumberPadButton(
                        symbol: '2',
                        controller: numberPadController,
                        onChange: () {
                        },
                      ),
                      
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                
                Expanded(
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      NumberPadButton(
                        symbol: 'Calculate',
                        controller: numberPadController,
                        onChange: () {},
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**SOLVED**
I have created focusNode and TextEditingController for each textfield, then added them to a Map. When button is tapped, i go through all textfield and work with a one that in the focus:

```
TextEditingController sideAController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController sideBController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController sideCController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController alphaController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController bettaController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController gammaController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numberPadController = TextEditingController();

  final sideANode = FocusNode();
  final sideBNode = FocusNode();
  final sideCNode = FocusNode();

  final alphaNode = FocusNode();
  final bettaNode = FocusNode();
  final gammaNode = FocusNode();
  Map<FocusNode, TextEditingController> focusNodes = {};

  focusNodes = {
      sideANode: sideAController,
      sideBNode: sideBController,
      sideCNode: sideCController,
      alphaNode: alphaController,
      bettaNode: bettaController,
      gammaNode: gammaController
    };
```

Now you just check and work with it:

```
void addSymbol(String symbol) {
    focusNodes.forEach((key, value) {
      key.hasFocus ? changeText(value, symbol) : null;
    });
  }
```

Comment: I think it would be better if you answer yourself (yes, you can do that) instead of including it in the question. It's even recommended to do it. You can also accept it so others would know the answer is right.

Comment: Hi. Thank you, i didn’t know, i gonna change it later.